# Не срабатывает useEffect, после перехода назад по useNavigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, react-router

Есть страница с редактированием абонента, после редактирования, к примеру, и нажатия кнопки сохранить или назад(не важно) браузер возвращается назад, но useEffect не срабатывает и соответственно нужно перезагружать вручную, чтобы данные обновились.

Для перехода использую метод `const navigate = useNavigate(); navigate(-1)`

Примечание: сайт расположен на сервере nginx

ВНИМАНИЕ!!!
Страница с редактированием информации и показа самой информации находятся на РАЗНЫХ компонентах. Для перехода в редактирование используется простая ссылка, а выхода из него вышеупомянутая функция
`navigate(-1)`
На локальном сервере все работает нормально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что за useEffect ? Дополните ваш вопрос кодом компонентов, где есть ошибки

Comment: Думаю нужно больше кода вокруг

Comment: Что за простая ссылка? Где использование navigate? Что такое iseffect и как он меняется?

Comment: href="ссылка". navigate используется во втором компоненте. iseffect срабатывает, как триггер при удалении данных абонента, чтобы перерендерить компонент

Comment: @Xamnack в react-route-dom существует Link, зачем использовать простую ссылку? Почему useEffect должен срабатывать, если он не зависит от смены страницы?

Comment: Исправьте ваш вопрос, чтобы код был в текстовых блоках. Для этого нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом, удаилте ваши скрины, скопируйте код, нажмите Ctrl+K  в окне редактирования и вставьте сюда код

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ответ оказался, на удивление простым и не очень(не подумал бы, что дело в этом). Я использовал обёртку для кнопок в виде `<NavLink to="ссылка"></NavLink` и useEffect начал срабатывать.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в dependencies хука `useEffect` `location.key`. `location.key` возьмешь из хука `useLocation`